# 'Ambiguous search mapping detected.' exception is thrown when springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0 is implemented in Spring Boot 2.3.6

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox, spring-boot-2, springfox-boot-starter

An 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous search mapping detected.' exception is thrown when I try to implement springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0 in Spring Boot 2.3.6.

I have two overloaded methods `public abstract Collection abc(int)` and `public abstract Page abc(int, Pagable)` in the same repository. The exception says that *both these methods are mapped to /abc! Tweak configurations to get to unambiguous paths!*.

Any suggestion to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got that error when following this Spring Content tutorial ( https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-with-versions-docs/ ) at executing the last call ( `curl -H 'Accept:application/hal+json' http://localhost:8080/files/` ): `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous search mapping detected. Both public abstract [...].LockingAndVersioningRepository.findAllVersions([...]Object) and public abstract java.util.List [...].findAllVersions([...]Object,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) are mapped to /findAllVersions! Tweak configuration to get to unambiguous paths!`

Comment: ... copying the interface into my local code and removing one of the ambiguous methods works, but certainly is not the way that the author of Spring Content intended...